# android -how to program button next for playing new media

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I already initialise a media by setDataSource and doing function prépare() start(). I want starting new média by click on button next, but what doing? Stop already media and do setDataSource and prépare() 
Start() for next media?

Answer (score 2):

Just reset mediaplayer before playing next song,then set new datasource and start it

```
public void startPlaying(String audioURL)
{
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    try 
    {
        if(audioURL != null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioURL);
            }

        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: In début du code for your methode startPlaying, how use méthode isPlaying for chek already media playing and clean it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a [callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) when the playback of your MediaPlayer has finished. There you can set a new Datasource.

Comment: Callback is for automatic play medias?